# How do I edit Vim's color scheme for better Syntax highlighting in Mac OS X Sierra/High Sierra?

Tags: macos, vim, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I realize syntax highlighting is not enabled when editing files in vim by default. How do I activate it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how to install syntax coloring in vim for Mac OS X Sierra/High Sierra:

**1. Download a vim color scheme:**

You can download one here: https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes

**2. Move color scheme into the `colors` directory inside your local `.vim` directory. (Create one if one does not exist.)**

(Assuming scheme is in local Downloads folder) `mv ~/Downloads/molokai.vim ~/.vim/colors/`

Create the `colors` and `~/.vim` directories if they do not exist: `mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors/`

**3. Set syntax coloring in Mac OS X Sierra/High Sierra:**

Run the following command in Terminal: `set term=builtin_ansi`

**4. Update/Create local .vimrc file:**

`vim ~/.vimrc`

Your `.vimrc` file should look similar to the following:

```
syntax on
colo molokai
```

**5. Restart terminal**

Comment: You are changing the `colorscheme` not syntax highlighting. Syntax highlighting is done by `:syntax enable`

Comment: thank you - really helped. few comments (at least for Catalina): a. no need for step 3 enable syntax coloring; b. no need to restart terminal c. .vimrc file should look sdomething like  

syntax enable
set t_Co=256
set background=light
colorscheme clean